# applicationWillEnterForeground - sometimes my app is very lazy

Tags: iphone, memory, ios4, memory-management, multitasking

My app contains many graphics and sounds. it's actually running very well - only if I go back in my app after a long time my app stops responding for about 2-7sec
I release my Images and sound (and all the rest) as soon as possible to keep the apps memory consumption as low as possible

how can I fix it?
thanks in advance

Comment: Your best bet would be to spawn a background thread to load all the resources back into your app. At least that way the rest of the app should be responsive (save the elements you're loading).

Comment: @RyanWersal  many thanks Ryan for your fast answer. how can i do this?

Comment: Updated my comment and submitted it as an answer. Probably not a very good one, but the best I can offer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to spawn a background thread to load all the resources back into your app. At least that way the rest of the app should be responsive (save the elements you're loading).

A good place to start learning about using threads with iOS and Objective-C would be the [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH1-SW1).